# partition fetched by kafka conusmer does not match the requested partition

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

```
kafka-server: 2.12_2.7.1
kafka-client: org.springframework.kafka && spring-kafka && 1.3.0.RELEASE
```

Both kafka-server and kafka-client are running in k8s container and error occured in kafka-client periodly: `Ignoring fetch response containing partitions {} since it does not match the requested partitions {}`

Here is the log:
[image: consumer log]

I wonder if anyone has encountered the same problem and is looking forward to solving it，thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear; when using group management you don't "request" a partition, they are assigned by the broker; you have to use manual assignment. In any case spring-kafka 1.3.0 has been out of support for many years. See https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support

Comment: Like I said, those versions are ancient (1.3.0 is nearly 5 years old). If you are still having problems with a supported version, post a minimal, complete, reproducible project someplace.

Comment: @GaryRussell Surely we are using the group management, and the error is throwed by kafka-client when spring-kafka using the `poll` method. See
[https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/e18335dd953107a61d89451932de33d33c0fd207/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/Fetcher.java#L211](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/e18335dd953107a61d89451932de33d33c0fd207/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/Fetcher.java#L211)

Comment: See my previous comment. You might have better luck asking about kafka-clients internals on one if their mailing lists. Spring is just a user of those clients. But I am sure they will want you to try a current version first.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks.However, this is a project that pursues stability. If it is upgraded, Spring will need to be upgraded, which will cost a lot

Comment: Unfortunately, stability and 5 year old software does not compute. You need to keep more up to date.

Comment: @GaryRussell OK. you know how to contact to kafka-clients internals?

Comment: Google “Kafka mailing lists”, but don’t expect an answer unless you can reproduce with a current version such as 3.0.1 or 3.1.0.

Comment: @GaryRussell Sorry to ask another question, if I upgrade the version of spring-kafka independently and the rest of the spring components(spring-core,spring-beans,spring-context,spring-context-support are now both in 4.3.4.RELEASE) remain the same, is this solution ok?  if so ,which spring-kafka version do you recommend?

Comment: The last Spring Framework 4.3.x version was 4.3.30 in December 2020 when support stopped; the currently supported versions of spring-kafka (2.8.4 and 2.7.12) require Spring Framework 5.3.18. The last spring-kafka that works with spring 4.3.30 was 1.3.11.

Comment: @GaryRussell That is to say spring-kafka cannot be upgraded separately, but must be upgraded together with all of spring's components, which can be quite expensive =.=  I'm going to use apache-kafka client directly. At least I'm not restricted in the selection of this component version. Well, anyway, thanks for your detailed reply again.